# Help needed to create a Search page using JSF, EJB, JPA & Primefaces with Pagination

Tags: jsf, jpa, datatable, ejb, primefaces

I am trying to make a search page using JSF, EJB, JPA & Primefaces with Pagination from an Oracle database table.

The page has two regions (1) region for entering search parameters
(2) region with a datatable showing the search result.  This datatable supports pagination.

I have used standard code generated using Netbeans IDE, but dont know how to pass the parameters while clicking the search button and show the results based on the search in the datatable.

Please help me with sample code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

For the input, just use a normal form like as you've created in a hello world tutorial. For presentation and pagination of the results, use PrimeFaces `LazyDataModel`. See also their [showcase example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableLazy.jsf).

Comment: I have tried the showcase example, but it is not detailing the data access part.  The Cars example has random data added to the list manually.

Comment: I have tried the showcase example, but it is not detailing the data access part from a database.  The Cars example has random data added to the list manually.  The pagination is working fine with the primefaces datatable component..

I am looking for sample code which can explain how a simple search page  with a search parameter section and on clicking the "Search" button after entering parameters the search has to be conducted on the database and outputs the data in a datatable.

Comment: Just replace the random list by your EJB/JPA call?